# Cannot add a specific character to the start of a char*, it only allows me to add it after in C?

Tags: c, string, struct, character, strcat

I am having issues adding a '-' to the start of a string in C, as it causes a seg-fault. It seems to have no issue adding a '-' to the end of the string. 
Essentially there are two fields to the struct, and if one of the fields has a value of '-1', the value is meant to be negative, and a '-1' is to be added to the other field in the struct. Adding the 'ch' to the start is causing it to segfault.

Here is the code:

```
        unsigned int toPrint = size(unitLiterals);
    qsort(unitLiterals->element, toPrint, sizeof(Literal*), sort);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < toPrint; i++){
        Literal*literal = get(unitLiterals, i);
        if (literal->isNegative == 1){
            printf("%s", literal->name);

        }
        else {
            char *ch = "-";
            strcat((char*)literal->name, ch);
            printf("%s", literal->name);
        }
        if (i != toPrint-1){
            printf(" ");
        }
        else {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Struct initialization:

```
Literal *newLiteralStruct (char *name, int i){
    Literal *this = malloc(sizeof(Literal));
    this->name = name;
    this->isNegative = i; 
    return this;
}
```

Literal in Header file:

```
typedef struct Literal Literal;

struct Literal {
    char* name;
    int isNegative;
};
```

Comment: `strcat` adds at the end, to insert before you have to move the chars after the position you insert (supposing you have the place for)

Comment: `char *ch = "=";` allocates only two bytes of memory: one for the `-` and one for the trailing null to terminate the string. Attempting to append to the end of it is going to cause you to write into memory that is allocated for something else or for some other process. You also need to show how you've defined the `name` field in `Literal`.

Comment: It won't work without the cast & I am not sure why. When I add it as strcat(literal->name, ch), the dash goes to the end of the literal, whereas I want it at the start.

Comment: The `ch` pointer points to a "buffer" thats 2 characters long, one is the hyphen, one is the (hidden) terminating zero. There is no space in this buffer for anything else.

Comment: I've edited it for it to be strcat((char*)literal->name, ch), but I would like the ch to be added at the start & not the end, and I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like the `ch` to be added at the start & not the end, and I don't know how to fix this.

Don´t use `strcat` for this. `strcat` always appends a copy of the string pointed to by the second argument to the end of the string pointed to by the first argument, not the start of it.

You can either Use a buffer and sequence of calls to `strcpy` instead:

```
 char *ch = '-';                          // Note the `-` is a character, not a string.
 char buf[N];                   
 buf[0] = *ch;                            // Copy `-` to the first element of `buf`. 
 strcpy(&buf[1], literal->name);          // Copy the string in `name` to `buf`,
                                          // starting at the second element of `buf`.   
 strcpy(literal->name, buf);              // Copy the string in `buf` back to `name`.
 printf("%s", literal->name);
```

Note that `name` must have an extra element hold the added `-` character and of course an element to store the terminating null character. Also the buffer needs to be capable to hold the string in `name` plus the added `-` and the null character.

You can also omit `ch` as it is not needed and make the code a little more compact:

```
 char buf[N];
 buf[0] = '-';
 strcpy(&buf[1], literal->name);
 strcpy(literal->name, buf);
 printf("%s", literal->name);
```

---

Or you can sort each character of the string in `name` one element forward (including the null character) and then assign `'-'` to the first element of `name`:

```
size_t len = strlen(literal->name);
for ( size_t i = 0; i < (len + 1); i++ )
{
    literal.name[i+1] = literal.name[i];
}
literal.name[0] = '-';
```

But again here, `name` requires to be capable to hold the string + the `'-'` + the null character.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried this, alongside using strdup to make a duplicate of literal->name. However, clang is giving me an error of 'warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]' in regards to buf[1].

Comment: @ckyzm My mistake. Forgot the `&` before. Corrected.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much. May I ask why we use buf[0]? Sorry, I'm new to C & am just looking for more clarity!

Comment: @ckyzm Subscript indexing of arrays start at `0`, not `1` in C. So `buf[1]` is actually the second element, not the first.

Comment: @ckyzm Is that what you meant or something else?

Comment: That does clear up some conceptual issues, I was more wondering why we can't just use char '-' on its own and require an array initialization.

Comment: @ckyzm It is just one possible way to achieve what you want. You *could* also sort each and every character (including the null character) of the string inside `name` one element forward and then assign `'-'` to the first element of `name` - It´s up to you. But as the `strcpy` use is very handy and the memory allocation of the buffer isn´t something to explicitly complain about this way fits pretty well. - You could also dynamically allocate the buffer and free it after its use if that is a problem.

Comment: @ckyzm I added the sorting version (without using a buffer) to the answer.